# "This XML file does not appear to have any style information..." Primefaces Error

Tags: primefaces

It seems an old qs , but i am not getting any proper suggestion.
Steps to produce error :
Scenario One  : 
1 : Logging in two tabs of same browser with same user credential. 
2 : Logging out from one tab .
3 : Logging in again.
I am seeing  : This XML file does not appear to have any style information......,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <partial-response id="j_id1">
- <changes>
- <update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0">
- <![CDATA[ 1ZFe3NbsDVn3BWdUDEmAPV96v XXXXXXXX...]]> 
</update>
</changes>
</partial-response>
```

Scenario 2 :
The same error when the  restart tomcat and logging in .
Please suggest me How to fix this.
My Web.xml content :

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**I m using Primeface 4 with jsfVersionMojarra-2.1.26  also 2.2.4 Even i am shocked why both versions are in my pom. Anyway this i will check.)** . But i am  pretty sure this will not cause this issue.

Comment: Please anyone can help on this issue .

Comment: how did you resolve the issue?

Comment: I resolved it, my problem was coming from p:socket which uses javascript on load

Comment: @TheGIsSilent : I am still facing this error , but luckily our application is being migrated to AJS. So I escaped :)

Comment: I still have not found any solution, so all I have to do is live with it for now

Comment: Hi there, I am facing the same issue (randomly showing the "xml file does not appear to have any style information" error). In my use case, I have a p:poll component and p:socket on the same page. I am running PrimeFaces 5.3 on JBoss EAP 6.4. Can you elaborate more on how you solved your problem? You simply removed the p:socket? From my experience PrimeFaces Push doesn't play nicely with JBoss EAP 6.4 as I encountered several other issues such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38365146/jsf-page-displays-zero-intermittently.