# jsf page displays zero intermittently

Tags: java, spring, jsf, primefaces, jboss

I am using JSF 2.1 + PrimeFaces 5.3 + Spring 4.2 on JBoss EAP 6.4, and I encounter a very weird issue intermittently. The page will simply respond with a zero (0) in the generated HTML (see attached screenshot). I believe this is not a browser issue as I have experienced this on both Chrome and Firefox. Anyone has any advice? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: *Anyone has any advice?* Try and make it consistently reproducible, then post a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You might also find enabling more logging helpful.

Comment: Please share your code as well. What you trying to do ? The above information is not proper or sufficient to help

Comment: Please, share the JSF code and also the rendered HTML page (the HTML code, not the screenshot).

Comment: sorry for the ambiguity but I was in the midst of trying to find a pattern and reproduce the issue. Unfortunately I couldn't reproduce it yet. This issue was encountered by others and I thought someone here might have had the same issue before. I won't post such an ambiguous question again in the future. If I do find a solution, I will post it here for the benefit of others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation, this was due to Atmosphere and JBoss writing to the same response object -> https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/atmosphere-framework/nCZcYgVVkY0/G0Cr79k4jnAJ